# Meaning of また今度、使ってくれよな

Tags: meaning

I'd like to ask if I'm correct in reading the following phrase as "(Please) use it again sometime!":

> また今度、使ってくれよな！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically you're asking them to use it the next time, but it should suit your purposes fine.  If you explicitly want to leave it as a general "sometime", you can change 今度 to いつか with no adverse effect.